# Javascript Compare two Arrays on first four characters only

Tags: javascript, arrays

http://jsfiddle.net/kg0bs9r7/

I have three unordered lists of images (delivered by arrays) which I drag and Drop the images around in
a quiz into the correct columns /arrays

```
  var arrays = [
['apple_0.jpg', 'orange_1.jpg', 'banana_0.jpg', 'pear_4.jpg', 'fish_5.jpg', 
 'pancake_7.jpg', 'taco_8.jpg', 'pizza_9.jpg'],
['taco_2.jpg', 'fish_5.jpg', 'apple_0.jpg', 'pizza_3.jpg'],
['banana_6.jpg', 'pizza_4.jpg', 'fish_3.jpg', 'apple_0.jpg']
];


  var result = arrays.shift().filter(function(v) {
  return arrays.every(function(a) {
    return a.indexOf(v) !== -1;
});
});


   document.write('<pre>' +
           JSON.stringify(result,null,4)
           + '</pre>');
```

At present this works when the whole object name  is  exactly the same
"apple_0.jpg"
Objective: I  want it to find all apple and fish and pizza regardless of _[variable].jpg suffix

```
i.e  Substring of object in array
```

Comment: please add the code to the question.

Answer (score 1):

You could normalize the array by taking the value without the unwanted parts and reduce the array by looking for common elements.

```js
const
    arrays = [['apple_0.jpg', 'orange_1.jpg', 'banana_0.jpg', 'pear_4.jpg', 'fish_5.jpg', 'pancake_7.jpg', 'taco_8.jpg', 'pizza_9.jpg'],['taco_2.jpg', 'fish_5.jpg', 'apple_0.jpg', 'pizza_3.jpg'],['banana_6.jpg', 'pizza_4.jpg', 'fish_3.jpg', 'apple_0.jpg']],
    result = arrays
        .map(a => a.map(s => s.slice(0, s.indexOf('_'))))
        .reduce((a, b) => a.filter(Set.prototype.has, new Set(b)));

console.log(result);
```